# set adapter to listView in asynctask

Tags: android, listview, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I'm having trouble on how to set an adapter to my listview in an asynchronous task. I have two options: One if there is internet on the device and the other if not. If the internet goes directly to search what I need to own Web service, whereas if there is no internet, looking into my local database. The second case works great in and out of the async task. Unfortunately the first case, the Internet, the task fails in but not out. I leave my code as I knew I could not play with the view within an asynchronous task, but my question is why does it work if there's no internet?

```
private class cargarListaInscripciones extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ValidacionMultiple.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        cargarVista();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Function :

```
public void cargarVista(){
      SessionManager manager = new SessionManager();
       rut_inscripcion = manager.getValue(this, "rut_inscripcion");
       nombreCliente = manager.getValue(this, "nombreCliente");
       user = manager.getValue(this, "nombreUser");
       folioEvento = manager.getValue(this, "folioEvento");
       codigoEvento = manager.getValue(this, "codigoEvento");
       seleccionValidadora = manager.getValue(this, "opcionVerificadora");
       nombreUser = manager.getValue(this, "nombreUser");
       hashUser = manager.getValue(this, "hashUsuario");
       listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
       Connection cn = new Connection();
       JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
       BaseDeDatos nueva = new BaseDeDatos();
       if(cn.isNetworkAvailable(ValidacionMultiple.this) || seleccionValidadora.equals("Mixto")){
           urls = Config.URL_BASE + nombreCliente + "/"
                    + Config.URL_VALIDACION_RUT_ARRAY + nombreUser + "/"
                    + hashUser + "/" + folioEvento + "/" + rut_inscripcion;
           if (manager.getValue(ValidacionMultiple.this,"checkin") != null) {
               id_checkin = nueva.idCheckin(ValidacionMultiple.this, manager.getValue(ValidacionMultiple.this,"checkin"));
               urls = urls + id_checkin;
           }
           System.out.println(urls);
           HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls);
           post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
            try {
                JSONObject dato = new JSONObject();
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(dato.toString());
                post.setEntity(entity);
                HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(post);
                String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                JSONObject respJSON = new JSONObject(respStr);
                json = respJSON;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("ServicioRest", "Error!", ex);
            }
            System.out.println("JSON: " + json);
            try {
                JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("Inscripciones");
                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject inscripcion = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
                    RowItem item = new RowItem(inscripcion.getString("nombre"),inscripcion.getString("ticket"), inscripcion.getString("asiento") , inscripcion.getString("numero"),images[0] , Integer.parseInt(inscripcion.getString("inscripcion_id")), inscripcion.getString("hash"), Integer.parseInt(inscripcion.getString("validado")));
                    rowItems.add(item);
                }
                adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple, rowItems );
                //Line 141 
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }else{
           //Modo local o mixto.
           rowItems = nueva.getInscripcionsByRut(this, rut_inscripcion);
           adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple, rowItems );
           listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       }
}
```

Error Internet :

```
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:5404)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1076)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4175)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10894)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10849)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.widget.AbsListView.resetList(AbsListView.java:2290)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:511)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:451)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.ValidacionMultiple.cargarVista(ValidacionMultiple.java:141)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.ValidacionMultiple$cargarListaInscripciones.doInBackground(ValidacionMultiple.java:87)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.ValidacionMultiple$cargarListaInscripciones.doInBackground(ValidacionMultiple.java:1)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: See this `08-10 09:54:31.837: E/AndroidRuntime(7417): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.` Most probably you are trying to update the UI from background thread.

Comment: you can't set adapter in background thread. Only on the main thread. Set it in onPostExecute, or using runOnUiThread, or using Handler

Comment: @VladMatvienko What I have more than clear, but as I said there, it will work on one case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

This línea is bad.

```
adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple, rowItems );
```

You have this, but should be your aplicación context
I dont know very well your code, but change to this:

adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(ValidacionMultiple.this, R.layout.lista_validacion_multiple, rowItems );

And second:

Your must that in the post execute method,in that method you can access to the main thread.

Regards.

Comment: Thanks !!, I realized that and works well! thank you!

Comment: Ok, happy for that. Please mark the answer as accepted to en the thread of the conversación. Regards.